# how can i make this script suitable for converting excel files with more than one sheet inside?

Tags: performance, csv, file-upload, xlsx, converters

```
import pandas as pd
from xlsx2csv import Xlsx2csv
from io import StringIO
def read_excel(path: str, sheet_name: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    buffer = StringIO() #to read and 
    Xlsx2csv(path, outputencoding="utf-8", sheet_name=sheet_name).convert(buffer)
    buffer.seek(0)
    df = pd.read_csv(buffer)
    return df
```

how can i make this script suitable for converting excel files with more than one sheet inside? It works only for xlsx file with one sheet at the moment...

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use xlsx2csv module? If not, you could try this with Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
for sheet in ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2']:
    df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx', sheetname=sheet)
```

Comment: Yes because for huge dataframe it's such a faster way, so I was trying to do that

Comment: Can you tell me why with this code it consider only the first sheet?

Comment: In your code read_excel is taking sheetname as a parameter. You could try calling the method for each sheetname.

Comment: Check this link. It says you can use sheetid parameter. It says if sheetid is passed as 0, it returns all sheets. https://github.com/dilshod/xlsx2csv/blob/master/xlsx2csv.py

Comment: No it gives me some errors. How can I covert all sheets and then select the one I want? In your opinion